# Creating an account/access to an VServer for a PHP/MySQL/Apache developer

Tags: user-accounts, user, privileges

I normally work with my server on my own, but now I have an external developer with whom I have never worked before. I need to work with him for a longer period of time before giving him full access to my server.

Right now his job will be restricted to working in only one directory. Basically he only needs to use

- PHP
- MySQL
- Apache
- adding/editing/deleting files and folders within this folder: /var/www/xyz
- Restarting Apache + MySQL

What steps do I need to take to give him enough rights to work independently on my server doing the above without giving him too much (= unnecessary) rights?

Can anyone help me out how to create this kind of account?